# c# regular expression always returns errors

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I have got two regular expression in my c# project, the one works the other doesnt.

```
Regex RX = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");
if (!RX.IsMatch(emailInput.Text))
{
    errorMessage = "Email is invalid!";
}
```

This one checks if the email is actually an email, I wanted to the the same for username. Where I check for username length and special characters.

```
new Regex(@"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15}$");
if (!RX.IsMatch(usernameInput.Text))
{
    errorMessage = "Username is invalid!";
}
```

Somehow everytime I run my project it returns username is invalid, which I dont understand. It doesnt matter what I type as username it always returns the errorMessage.

Comment: Some samples would be nice.

Comment: The [username regex works](http://ideone.com/x6LMbG).

Comment: Did you assign `new Regex` to `RX`?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to check for email address validity. There are so many edge-cases. Most of the **valid** email addresses I *(try to)* use daily are flagged as invalid by your regular expression, and by so many others.

Comment: Possibly this is just for demo purposes, but you should not use that email regex in the real world. It will fail most valid email addresses.

Comment: I use this regex for my demo project, I wasn't planning on using it in the real world.

Comment: There are standard libraries for validating email addresses, use those instead.

Comment: I have a `.` *(dot)* before the `@` sign, not allowed by your regex. I have email address on a **subdomain**, not allowed. I have email address on a **five letter top domain**, not allowed. I use the `+` sign before the `@` sign to separate into folders, not allowed. One of my domain names has 37 characters, not allowed. The list goes on...

Comment: I agree with the others... That email validation is broken. For instance it will fail all .co.uk addresses but allow x@y#zz and the like.

Comment: `emailInput.Text.Contains("@")` is enough, and allows users to use real-world email addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you don't want *creating* `Regex` instance at all, let .Net do it for you:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(usernameInput.Text, 
                   @"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15}$")) {
  errorMessage = "Username is invalid!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is working, but I think you forgot to assign RX to your new regex.

```
new Regex(@"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15}$");
```

should be

```
RX = new Regex(@"^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[._()\[\]-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9._()\[\]-]{3,15}$");
```